# Flutter/Dart - how do I trigger AnimationController animations in individual widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter/Dart - how do I trigger AnimationController animations in individual widgets?

I have an AnimationController set up to animate between a selected and deselected state for a custom chip Widget. But in context, I have several chips and want them to be mutually exclusive, so that selecting one deselects the others. I've really been struggling to figure this one out - while I can update the state of a single tapped chip but when that chip is tapped, I don't know how to notify the other chips that they should animate to deselected.

Overall I'm having trouble figuring out what should be pulled out into the parent of all these chips and what logic I should keep in the individual chips. Right now my AnimationController and Animations are all in the individual chips and I tried sticking some ChangeNotifier/Provider stuff into the parent Widget.

Might be that I'm new to Dart/Flutter's declarative ways, but any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TweenAnimationBuilder-class.html

Comment: Hey, it's hard to help without some code, widget structure, etc. Can you provide some information to the question?